# How do I check whether value in active cell contains any letter or not?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

For example cell "A1" is linked to cell "B1", so in formula bar for cell "A1" we have:
=B1

How can I check whether value in cell "A1" contains letter B?

I tried the following:

```
Dim Criteria_3 As Boolean

Dim Value As Range
Set Value = Selection

Dim x As Variant
Set x = Cells

Dim text As String

    For Each x In Value

        If IsNumeric(x) Then

        Criteria_3 = VBA.InStr(1, x.Formula, text) > 0
```

As soon as value of "Text" is "" it does not work and I really struggle to fined the right solution.

Comment: `Value` , `Text` both of them are keywords I suggest you use some other variable name just to avoid confusion and possible errors. To check if a str has `B` use this if instr(chkstr,"B",0) > 0 then` .

Comment: is there any function for any letter? "B" is just an example, factually it can be any letter a,b,c,d,e....aa,ab,ac....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your goal is to check whether the cell contains any valid range reference, then you could go like this

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet001").Range("A1:A20") '<== jus a test range, set it as per your needs
    MsgBox IsCellReference(cell.Formula)
Next cell

End Sub

Function IsCellReference(text As String) As Boolean    
On Error Resume Next
IsCellReference = Not Range(Replace(text, "=", "")) Is Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

your question is not really conclusive, so here are two options:

To check wheter the **value** contains B:

```
blnCheck = 0 < InStr(1, rngCell.Value, "B")
```

To check wheter the **Formula** contains B:

```
blnCheck = 0 < InStr(1, rngCell.Formula, "B")
```

Comment: is there any function for any letter? "B" is just an example, factually it can be any letter a,b,c,d,e....aa,ab,ac....

Comment: Might help to specify your question a little more. Do you want to check if the string contains ONE letter? Multiple Letters? If the string is numeric?

Regardsless this link might help you: https://techniclee.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/isletter-function-for-vba/

Comment: Thank you for that link about "IsLetter function". it helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your null string problem:

> As soon as value of "Text" is "" it does not work and I really struggle to fined the right solution.

That's because you're using `VBA.InStr(1, x.Formula, text)` and in this case `1` is an invalid index on a string of length 0. You can omit that, or you can code around it like:

```
If Len(Trim(x.Formula)) = 0 Then
   '## Do nothing
Else
   Criteria_3 = VBA.InStr(1, x.Formula, text) > 0
End If
```

**To your specific question of identifying when a value contains *any* alpha character(s):**

You can use a function like this to test whether a value contains *any* letter, by evaluating the Ascii code for each character, and break when True:

```
Function ContainsAnyLetter(val) As Boolean
Dim ret As Boolean
Dim str$, ch$
Dim i As Long
str = LCase(CStr(val))

For i = 1 To Len(str)
    ch = Mid(str, i, 1)
    If 97 <= Asc(ch) And Asc(ch) <= 122 Then
        ret = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

ContainsAnyLetter = ret


End Function
```

[image]

In your code, you could call it like:

```
Criteria_3 = ContainsAnyLetter(x.Value)  '## or x.Formula, depending on your needs
```

Comment: Thanks! Easily created the code i needed after reading your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LIKE`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx

Something like `if rngCell.value like "*B*" then`

Comment: or `Like "*[A-Za-Z]*"` to check for any letters.